# My C# code can't see my directory in my C drive...even though the directory exists

Tags: c#, directory

My directory is at C:\Testing\Event Log 123

The 123 portion is a timestamp. My code runs and generates a timestamped directory in C:\Testing upon completion. I have this piece of code that checks if that directory exists:

```
string dirToCopy = @"C:\Testing\Event Log " + timestamp;
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(dirToCopy))
{
   APILog.AddMessage("Event System log directory found.");
}
else
{
   APILog.AddMessage("Event System log directory not found.");
 }
```

The directory does exist at that location, but the else statement's log message is what gets displayed. I don't think there's an issue with permissions, as I'd be getting a security exception if that was the case...so why can't my code see the directory that I can see with my own eyeballs right now? I tried outputting dirToCopy to make sure that it matches the directory's actual name. They match, so I'm surprised that my code doesn't see it.

Edit for more info: My code runs on a client PC. It generates the directory and pastes it into the main PC's C:\Testing directory. The main PC's C:\Testing directory is a sort of shared directory that the client can also access. Does this matter, though? C:\Testing is on the main PC, and I'm running the code on the main PC.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code posted.  I suspect there's likely something simple being overlooked when debugging this, but we can't know that.

Comment: Do you have rights to the directory?

Comment: I should have rights. I edited the post to add more information. I have a main PC that has a client PC. The code that generates the log directory runs on the client PC. It pastes the directory onto the main PC's C drive, which is available to the client PC as a sort of shared drive.

Comment: Do verfy that user under which client PC is running has access to share drive you are talking about

Comment: The user is signed in as Administrator and has permissions.

Comment: when you say sort of shared directory? what it means? do you mean UNC path? or actual shared directory?

Comment: @HandleThatError see my updated answer if that solves your problem

Comment: If you are using admin privileges then you must have a dollar sign ($) in front of the folder to get access.

Answer (score 0):

So the directory You're looking for is `"C:\Testing\Event Log2016.01.26"`
or maybe `"C:\Testing\Event Log\2016.01.26"`

the point being - the slash at the end ? isn't it missing ?

you could also consider using `Path.Combine()` for building the path string

Comment: The time stamp is not the name of a separate directory. I'm appending the timestamp to the end of "Event Log" and it forms the name of the directory. For example, when I generate the directory its name ends up being something like "C:\Testing\Event Log 20160126"

Comment: what about the context that You're executing Your code ? maybe it's a permissions issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what MSDN says

If you do not have at a minimum read-only permission to the directory, the Exists method will return false.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx

So it does not throws security exception....so do check once if you have read permission on that directory

**Update**

If it is shared directory then your path should look like this

```
string dirToCopy = @"\\MainPC\Testing\Event Log 123" (Assuming testing folder is shared)
```

If it is UNC path then your path should like this

```
string dirToCopy = @"\\MainPC\C$\Testing\Event Log 123"
```